# C - How to get the 4 least significant bits in a Char

Tags: c, bit

I´m new in the C language, and I´m trying to get the 4 least significant bits from an unsigned char. So far I have no idea how to get them. I´ll appreciate any help

Comment: Well, `c & 0xF`. But what does this have to do with *arrays*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295279/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-the-4-least-significant-bits-in-a-byte-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple *bitwise* logic:

```
unsigned char c = 120;
unsigned char lsb4 = c & 0x0F;
```

Where `0x0F` represents the binary value `00001111`.

If you're [using GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244726/why-doesnt-c-have-binary-literals), it's even more literal:

```
unsigned char lsb4 = c & 0b00001111;
```

Technically the leading `0`s are not required here but they're included to help illustrate which bits are being selected.